# Database SSH connection cannot be established from Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, ssh, database-connection

I can't establish a database connection from MySQL client Workbench through SSH.  If I click Test Connection I get the error: `ERROR local variable 'chan' referenced before assignment` in the first step.
However I was able to connect from MySQL server through the command line, via SSH.  I was also able to connect to my local database with Workbench.  I am using Ubuntu with KDE 14.10 and the problem started with the update, so I guess it has to do with that, but I don't know how. Please let me know if you'd like further information. 
Thank you in advance,

PS I saw a similar problem without a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047384/mysql-workbench-over-ssh-wont-connect).

Comment: I'm having the same `ERROR local variable 'chan' referenced before assignment` problem.

Comment: MySQL bug report: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75075

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here a solution to fix this issue under Debian/Ubuntu:

**1** First, close Mysql Workbench!

**2** Apply the patch:

```
sudo cd /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/
sudo wget https://launchpadlibrarian.net/189450207/paramiko.patch
sudo patch -p1 < paramiko.patch
```

**3** Start Mysql Workbench, it's now working!

Comment: Thanks for checking it out.  Unfortunately I still got errors =(
sudo patch -p1 < paramiko.patch
patching file modules/wb_admin_ssh.py
Hunk #1 FAILED at 84.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 99.

Comment: Wouldn't know where to go from there, any help appreciated.

Comment: Try using the ubuntu/debian package version? Uninstall you current version and install from apt: sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench

Comment: This is helpful.  I found out I had mixed the installations from source and `apt-get` at some point and I wasn't well aware.  Going through removals and such...

Answer (score 0):

If you use python 2.x, try using python3?

This bug is probably related: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74960

Edit: confirmed, I have tried with python 2.x and have this error into mysql/workbench/log/wb.log:

```
5:35:38 [INF][wb_admin_control.py:query_server_installation_info:767]: Currently connected to MySQL server version 'unknown', conn status = None, active plugins = []
15:35:38 [ERR][sshtunnel.py:notify_exception_error:233]: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/mysql-workbench/sshtunnel.py", line 315, in accept_client
    sshchan = transport.open_channel('direct-tcpip', self._target, local_sock.getpeername())
  File "/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/wb_admin_ssh.py", line 116, in wba_open_channel
    raise e
EOFError

15:35:38 [ERR][wb_admin_control.py:server_polling_thread:492]: Error creating SQL connection for monitoring: MySQLError("Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0 (code 2013)",)
15:35:56 [INF][   base library]: Notification GNFocusChanged is not registered
```

Comment: Yes, `python --version` gives me `Python 2.7.8`.  How do I set up Workbench to use Python 3?